# How to convert MIMO transfer function to SS model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a system with 2 inputs and 2 outputs
described by 4 tf's with common denominators of order 4.

How can I convert this system to a state-space model of order 4 ?

If I use the following code I am getting MIMO SS model of order 8 while MIMO SS model of order 4 is expected. Please suggest any solution to this problem.

```
numr11=[1 2 3];
denr11=[1 2.273 14.03 20.15 27.82];

R11=tf(numr11,denr11);

numr12=[3 2 1];

R12=tf(numr12,denr11);

numr21=[4 5 6];

R21=tf(numr21,denr11);

numr22=[7 8 9];

R22=tf(numr22,denr11);

R=[R11,R12;R21,R22]

sys1= ss(R)

sys_final=minreal(sys1)
```

Comment: What does it mean "order 4 is expected" ? Do you know the "correct answer"? If so, can you also post it.

Comment: Order 4 means, A matrix should be 4x4, for this example B should be 4x2 and C should be 2x4...

Comment: Oh, let me clarify: why do you mean that it is expected to be of order 4? why not 6, 123 or 5? why do you know that its going to be of order 4?

Comment: Bcoz its denominator is of 4th order which I have just edited now, so A must be 4x4 and corresponding no. of eigen values should be 4...but A is coming 8x8 order and hence producing 8 eigen values...???

Comment: Dear Ander Biguri...Plz reply or correct me if I m doing something wrong...????

Comment: Mmmmm my control theory is a bit rusty. However, it look slike you have 2 inputs, and 2 outputs, with each of them having a 4th order tf. The state space is of order 8 because you have 2 inputs of 4th order, thus 8. If you see the a matrix, you will realise that the outputs are not coupled (there are 2 4x4 zero submatrices inside)

Comment: Okz thanks for your quick reply...you are very right dear..but what is the solution of this problem...how to remove extra four states in this case...so that our final A matrix will look like 4x4.

Comment: No one is there to suggest any solution to this problem??????????????

Comment: You can not just remove states. If you have your problem descrived as you have, it needs 8 for an accurate description, as fas as I know. But I am not an expert.

Comment: Dear Biguri, thanks for you efforts..my problem must be described by 4 states only...bcoz the degree of the denominator is 4..MATLAB is giving just replica of the four states that's why we are getting 8....I thought you can solve my problem....anyways let me see and thanks a lot once again..